# What sort of testing is appropriate when your server people want to apply updates to .NET Framework?

Tags: .net

My company's server people are looking to apply some updates to the .NET Framework (in this case I think it's .NET 4 SP1) on the company's servers and desktops.

The test strategy they want to implement is to install it into a test environment and step through the applications' UIs. The applications are a combination of SharePoint, Dynamics CRM and some other business critical third party .NET applications.

I'm particularly dubious about the validity of this test strategy as I think that without considerable effort, very little of the code will actually be exercised. Secondly, without any external data validation, how can they be sure of anything?

So, what I'm looking for is some advice and supporting evidence regarding what sort of testing is valid and worthwhile when pushing out updates of this sort.

Comment: Have to say I do object to the close votes. I am specifically looking for some evidence to support a chosen test strategy (so have to disagree with the not constructive vote), though I think I should have posted this to Server Fault rather than here.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4 Service Pack 1 shouldn't have a huge impact on your application. You can go through release notes to check if any side-effects are related to your application.

The usual release testing should be enough, I guess.

A full regression will give you more confidence, but you might not have enough resources.

A good unit tests coverage will help, but again if you don't have it than there's little you can do.

Comment: Unit tests are out of the question - the applications are third party applications. There's also no regression test suite for the same reasons. I've got no idea how the applications are built so I don't think I can intelligently test against the release notes. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: For third party applications you can do UI testing. You might want to get some actual users if possible and go through more complex functionality. Can't really think about anything else. I don't expect Microsoft service pack to bring down Microsoft Sharepoint or CRM. They usually test own products first ;-)

Comment: I think we're closing the circle on the argument here. Clicking through an application tests very few of the pathways through the application - think validation conditions, divide by zeros, ability to write data, etc. As for SharePoint and CRM, I don't think so either but I'd like some evidence. I've had no success finding any and it's the only way I'm going to be able to make an argument.